# Unable to login in Wordpress Admin on Local

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I am currently doing work for a live wordpress site and created a local installation using local by flywheel. When I use the admin credentials on the live site it logs in fine. However when I try to login on the local installation using the same credentials it says invalid username or password. I checked the users table in the sql database file and the username is in the table. How do i change the password on the local installation?

Edit: I created the local version of the website using the wp-content folder and a sql file of the exported databases from the live website. This was how I was instructed per local by flywheel's tutorial

Comment: Are you using the same database or a local version of the same tables etc? Please update your question to include as much pertinent information as possible.

Comment: Yes I am using the same database as the live version.

Comment: If you are using a copy of the database then you are not using the same database!

Comment: If it's a copy then wouldn't the credentials be the same? Sorry this is the first time I've had to copy a live site to a local version. How do I proceed to access the wp-admin on the local version then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/

This article will probably be your best bet. While it holds all the information. I highly recommend either going down the route of wp-cli or direct to the database.

For MySQL this will effectively change the password for you

```
UPDATE wp_options SET user_pass=MD5('newpass') WHERE user_login = <username>;
```

However, for wp-cli you can run this

```
wp-cli user update <username> --user_pass=<newpass>
```

Overall wp-cli is the *best* option because it has tooling to solve so many other problems too!
Good luck out there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up using the FTP method but it worked like a charm. Since it was local i just opened the functions.php file for my theme and added `wp_set_password( 'password', 1 );` 
after the opening `<?php` tag. After I was logged in I just deleted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Below article will set a resetting your password, and you can go to `wp_users` and edit your account pass

https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/